# Login OpenERP with XML-RPC

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

I have been searching the web for a few days now, but can't find anything that i can understand. I am looking for a way to login to OpenERP from a website i created. I want to fill the fields with the user data, and then redirect to OpenERP and login with that data.

Basically, i want to login to OpenERP from another webpage. I know this needs to be done with XML-RPC calls. But i don't know how to do it.

I need someone to explain this to me. How do i program the login using Xml-rpc?
I have checked the link: https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html/

But this didn't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

basically, send an XML-RPC message containing parameters like the username and password to OpenERP's 'common' web service address.

Here is the sample login function from PHP xmlrpc i used to use:

```
<?php
include("xmlrpc.inc");

function login(){

    $user      = "admin";
    $password  = "1234";
    $dbname    = "devel";
    $server_url= "http://127.0.0.1:8069/xmlrpc/";

    $conn      = new xmlrpc_client($server_url . 'common');
    $msg       = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
    $msg->addParam( new xmlrpcval($dbname,   "string") );
    $msg->addParam( new xmlrpcval($user,     "string") );
    $msg->addParam( new xmlrpcval($password, "string") );
    $resp      = $conn->send( $msg );
    $val       = $resp->value();
    $this->id        = $val->scalarval();
    return $this->id>0 ? $this->id  : -1 ;
}
```

It will return -1 if login failed, otherwise the user ID from OpenERP.

XML-RPC interfacing to OpenERP is complicated and not very well documented. But, I've wrote a detailed e-book about using xmlrpc, search in Google Play for "Advanced PHP and OpenERP Interfacing Using PHP XML-RPC Library".

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which language you want this, I am familiar with the PHP call so will explain it to you in that context.

Technically, there is no real login function. You send the API the parameters and it will respond with a user_id. And this user_id is then used when you make your next calls. Hence if you receive a user_id, 'login' was successful and you can use the user_id to proceed. If the login details were incorrect, you will receive a response stating so.

```
    include ("../xmlrpc-3.0.0.beta/lib/xmlrpc.inc"); //the PHP XML RPC library

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
    $dbname = 'database_name';                             //Name of the DB you want to access
    $user = 'admin';                                       //The user you want to 'login'
    $pwd = 'admin';                                        //The user's password
    $url = 'localhost:8069';                               //The server of OpenERP
    $sock = new xmlrpc_client($url."/xmlrpc/common");      //Sock files location on server
    $client = new xmlrpc_client($url."/xmlrpc/object");    //client files location on server
//THE CALL
    $sock_msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');                    //Type of message (all other cases use 'execute')     
    $sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($dbname, "string")); //1st param - Database
    $sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));   //2nd param - Username
    $sock_msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pwd, "string"));    //3rd param - password
    $sock_resp = $sock->send($sock_msg);                   //Sends the message with parrams

    if ($sock_resp->errno != 0)
    {
      //if there is an error
      echo  'error.<br>';
    }
    // if your have successfully logged in, the errno == 0
    elseif ($sock_resp->errno == 0)
    {
     //a user_id will be returned
      $sock_val = $sock_resp->value();
      $user_id = $sock_val->scalarval();

      //YOUR NEXT CALL HERE

    }
```

Comment: You can use `print_r($sock_resp);` to have the complete response printed to your screen.